# barnyard missing SID msg map file from snort

Tags: snort

I installed snort (currently ver. 2.9.7.0-5) then compiled Barnyard2 Version 2.1.14 (Build 337). At first try with:

```
sudo ./barnyard2 -c ../etc/barnyard2.conf -o /var/log/snort/snort.alert
```

I get `Unable to open SID file '/etc/snort/sid-msg.map' (No such file or directory)`. Which is true, /etc/snort/sid-msg.map indeed is missing. I tried with the existing /etc/snort/community-sid-msg.map but then I get:

```
ERROR: [ParseSidMapLine()]: Unknown sidmap file version [0]
```

Am I missing something or what should I do in order to make it work?

```
lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

Comment: Please someone with appropriate reputation to add the tag _barnyard_, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that /etc/snort/community-sid-msg.map is usable but only after removing the containing comments e.g.:

```
cd ~
sudo grep -v -P "^#" /etc/snort/community-sid-msg.map > community-sid-msg-no-comments.map
# dir required by barnyard2 at runtime
sudo mkdir /var/log/barnyard2
# comment the line "config sid_file: /etc/snort/sid-msg.map" in your barnyard2/etc/barnyard2.conf
sudo ~/apps/opt/barnyard2/bin/barnyard2 -c ~/apps/opt/barnyard2/etc/barnyard2.conf -S community-sid-msg-no-comments.map -o -q /var/log/snort/snort.log
```

Though working the output is not quite complete. This line is an example output:

```
04/05-23:18:39.268639  [**] [1:485:4] Snort Alert [1:485:4] [**] [Classification: Misc activity] [Priority: 3] {ICMP} 46.223.181.179 -> 188.26.13.70
```

while an equivalent better one would be:

```
04/05-23:18:39.268639  [**] [1:485:4] ICMP Destination Unreachable Communication Administratively Prohibited [**] [Classification: Misc activity] [Priority: 3] {ICMP} 46.223.181.179 -> 188.26.13.70
```

The second (better one) line was generated using a sid file generated with:

```
python ~/compile/py-idstools/idstools/scripts/gensidmsgmap.py /etc/snort/rules/ > sid-msg-v1.map
```

Take the gensidmsgmap.py from https://github.com/jasonish/py-idstools/tree/master/idstools/scripts.